# Updating Matrix Using Data From Coerced Matrix

Tags: r, matrix, binary

Here is the code that I am working with:

```
  y <- c(0,5,10)
n <- 9 

R <- t(c(2.05, 2.05, 2.05, 2.55, 2.55, 2.55, 2.95, 2.95, 2.95))
R <- (replicate(3,R))
R <- (matrix(R, nrow=3))
R <- t(apply(R,1,sort))

mat <- t(sapply(y, function(test) pmax(seq(test, (test-n+1), -1), 0) ))
mat




P <- replicate(ncol(R),(c(6447.88,6447.88,6447.88)))

EnvTest <- new.env()
EnvTest$Orig <- 548453.5

FuncTest <- function(pp){
  EnvTest$Orig <- EnvTest$Orig-(P[,pp]-EnvTest$Orig*R[,pp]/1200)
  return(EnvTest$Orig)
}

Test<- rbind(EnvTest$Orig,
             do.call(rbind,lapply(1:9, FuncTest)))
x <- t(Test)
x
```

This produces:

```
     [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]     [,5]     [,6]     [,7]     [,8]     [,9]    [,10]
[1,] 548453.5 542942.6 537422.2 531892.4 526574.8 521245.9 515905.7 510726.1 505533.7 500328.6
[2,] 548453.5 542942.6 537422.2 531892.4 526574.8 521245.9 515905.7 510726.1 505533.7 500328.6
[3,] 548453.5 542942.6 537422.2 531892.4 526574.8 521245.9 515905.7 510726.1 505533.7 500328.6
```

Which is what I am telling the function to do so that is correct. But now I want to use some information from the matrix `R*(mat==0)` which is:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9]
[1,] 2.05 2.05 2.05 2.55 2.55 2.55 2.95 2.95 2.95
[2,] 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 2.55 2.95 2.95 2.95
[3,] 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00
```

So I tried to do something like this...

```
 FuncTest2 <- function(pp){
          EnvTest$Orig <- ifelse(R*(mat==0)==0,EnvTest$Orig,EnvTest$Orig-(P[,pp]-EnvTest$Orig*R[,pp]/1200))
                 return(EnvTest$Orig)
        }
        Test2<- rbind(EnvTest$Orig,
                     do.call(rbind,lapply(1:9, FuncTest2)))
        x2 <- t(Test2)
        x2
```

But that did not produce the desired outcome which is:

```
      [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]     [,5]     [,6]     [,7]     [,8]     [,9]    [,10]
[1,] 548453.5 542942.6 537422.2 531892.4 526574.8 521245.9 515905.7 510726.1 505533.7 500328.6
[2,] 548453.5 548453.5 548453.5 548453.5 548453.5 543171.1 538058.5 532933.3 527795.5 522645.1
[3,] 548453.5 548453.5 548453.5 548453.5  548453.5 548453.5 548453.5 548453.5  548453.5 548453.5
```

So basically if R*(mat==0) = 0 then `EnvTest$Orig <- 548453.5` does not change until the `R*(mat==0)` is  greater than zero the `EnvTest$Orig` does update.

**Another Attempt**

I also tried to do the following, but it did not work but I think that something along these lines will prove fruitful.

```
    maybe <- R*(mat==0)
    FuncTest2 <- function(pp, maybe){
        EnvTest$Orig <- if(maybe == 0) (EnvTest$Orig-0) else
        (EnvTest$Orig-(P[,pp]-EnvTest$Orig*R[,pp]/1200))
      return(EnvTest$Orig)
    }

Test2<- rbind(EnvTest$Orig,
              do.call(rbind,lapply(1:9, FuncTest2)))
x2 <- t(Test2)
x2
```

Comment: oh sorry something weird happened in the copy and past one second

Comment: @akrun is that better?

Comment: @akrun anything at first glance?

Comment: At first glance, I think the lengths may not be the same for `ifelse`

Comment: @akrun I was also thinking that maybe an sapply function with an if else statement inside FuncTest may do the trick but I couldn't get that to run

Comment: @akrun it is close but does not produce the right output

Comment: Anyway you got a posted solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, with respect to your `FuncTest()` and `FuncTest2()` computations, `R` is a constant, as it is not modified during those function calls or by the surrounding data manipulation (referring to the `do.call()`/`rbind()`/`t()` stuff). This is `R`:

```
R;
##      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9]
## [1,] 2.05 2.05 2.05 2.55 2.55 2.55 2.95 2.95 2.95
## [2,] 2.05 2.05 2.05 2.55 2.55 2.55 2.95 2.95 2.95
## [3,] 2.05 2.05 2.05 2.55 2.55 2.55 2.95 2.95 2.95
```

As you can see, none of its elements are zero. This means that the expression

```
R*(mat==0)==0
```

is equivalent to

```
mat!=0
```

since multiplication by `R` cannot turn a non-zero value into zero, or turn a zero into a non-zero value.

If you still want to parameterize the `ifelse()` conditional on `R`, perhaps because you may want to run this code for different values of `R` that can contain zeroes, then it should be rewritten as

```
R==0|mat!=0
```

Secondly, your code has a bit of a suspicious pattern with respect to the dimensionality of the state variable `EnvTest$Orig`. You initialize it to a one-element vector (548453.5), but on first run of `FuncTest()` it is immediately overwritten with a three-element vector, where the initial scalar was cycled 3 times to accommodate the three-element vectors `P[,pp]` and `R[,pp]`. From that point forward it is permanently a three-element vector. In `FuncTest2()` (first attempt), since `mat` and `R` are 3x9 matrices, the true and false arguments of the `ifelse()` vectorized ternary will be cycled to cover that dimensionality, and then `EnvTest$Orig` will be overwritten by the resulting 3x9 matrix. From that point forward it is permanently a 3x9 matrix.

You should probably think carefully about what dimensionality you want for `EnvTest$Orig` and stick to that from beginning to end. Judging from your expected output, it looks like you want it to be a vector of length 3, and thus you should be indexing the matrix in the `ifelse()` conditional:

```
FuncTest2 <- function(pp) {
    EnvTest$Orig <- ifelse(R[,pp]==0|mat[,pp]!=0,EnvTest$Orig,EnvTest$Orig-(P[,pp]-EnvTest$Orig*R[,pp]/1200));
    return(EnvTest$Orig);
};
EnvTest$Orig <- 548453.5;
Test2 <- rbind(EnvTest$Orig,do.call(rbind,lapply(1:9,FuncTest2)));
x2 <- t(Test2);
x2;
##          [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]     [,5]     [,6]     [,7]     [,8]     [,9]    [,10]
## [1,] 548453.5 542942.6 537422.2 531892.4 526574.8 521245.9 515905.7 510726.1 505533.7 500328.6
## [2,] 548453.5 548453.5 548453.5 548453.5 548453.5 548453.5 543171.1 538058.5 532933.3 527795.6
## [3,] 548453.5 548453.5 548453.5 548453.5 548453.5 548453.5 548453.5 548453.5 548453.5 548453.5
```

However, this result does not exactly match your expected output in the second row, and I'm not sure why.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I will take some time to digest it all. I was doing the calculation for the second row by hand so it is very possible that I simply made an error.

Comment: it is very strange that your answer does not work for the second updated value in x2 or x2[2,8]. Any ideas?

Comment: It does work: `EnvTest$Orig <- c(515905.7,543171.1,548453.5); FuncTest2(7);` results in `[1] 510726.1 538058.5 548453.5`. The exact calculation is `543171.1-(6447.88-543171.1*2.95/1200)`.